# AngularJS 1.5.5 app taking TOO MUCH TIME to load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi everyone I am currently facing a performance issue with an angularJS 1.5.5 app. The homepage takes **FOREVER** to load, even using the minified libraries it is taking up to 25s to load (just with one user accesing the app).

I first thought that it could be the server where is allocated, but no, if I run my app locally, takes about the same time. This is the waterfall diagram:
[Waterfall Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8qSk.png)

I am not sure why does it takes too long to serve the minified libraries along with the rest of the resources. Even in most of the posts that I have seen related to performance issues, I notice that these libraries are provided in less than a second, maybe 250-500 ms for each of them (maximum).

This is the way I am importing my libraries to my index:

```
<!--Minified Libraries--> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/min/angular_block_ui.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/min/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/lib/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.min.css">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/min/massautocomplete.min.css">

  <script src="js/resources/min/q.min.js"></script>``
  <script src="js/resources/min/fastclick.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/resources/min/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/resources/min/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/resources/min/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/resources/min/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/lib/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/lib/angular-autocomplete/massautocomplete.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/resources/min/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/resources/min/angular-file-upload.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/resources/min/roundProgress.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/resources/min/angular-charts.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/resources/min/circular1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/resources/min/circular2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/resources/min/angular_block_ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/lib/pdfmake/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/resources/min/vfs_fonts.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/lib/angular/angular-idle.min.js"></script>

  <script src="app/app.js"></script>
  <script src="app/service/CompensationSrvc.js"></script>
  <script src="app/service/security.js"></script>
  <script src="app/modules/common/controller/common.js"></script>
  <script src="app/modules/home/controller/home.js"></script>
  <script src="app/modules/import/controller/import.js"></script>
```

Thank you in advance!
Any help will be totally appreciated! I have been searching for an answer for the last days and nothing I have seen is as slow as this app.

**UPDATE:** I am almost sure that the problem is in the backend since the files are being served slowly.
The statement
 `app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"))` is at the top of the code, so I am not sure what should I improve to make it faster...

Comment: I don't know anything about angular but shouldn't your code be bundled? Having this many blocking requests at the start of your app would take a long time...

Comment: Where are theses scripts and link tag situed in the index.html file ? In the head tag ? In the body tag ?

Comment: Hi @Dominik I am do ont have too much experience on this, but I think the same, altough, I don't know how to change it

Comment: Hi @Julien This scripts are inside the head tag.